# Can't connect to database with Qt

Tags: qt, sqlite, qt4

I'm facing a weird problem. I'm creating Qt 4 code that connects to a Sqlite database 
using:

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
db.setDatabaseName("sb.sqlite");
bool db_ok = db.open();
```

When I execute the code from Qt Creator or the directly from the release folder I'm able to connect to the database but when I copy the release folder (that includes the database file) to another machine I can't connect for some reason.

I also tried using a full path to the database file:

```
db.setDatabaseName("C://release//sb.sqlite");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things:

First:

When writing out a path, you either need to use escaped back slashes: `\\` or use forward slashes: `/`

Trying to escape a forward slash in Qt, could give you problems.

Second:

When deploying a Qt App, all the necessary Qt modules need to be available, AND the Qt plugins that you need.

The Qt plugins only cause missing run-time functions, while the missing Qt modules with cause an immediate crash on loading.

The thread below should address the problem you are seeing:

http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/21518

> just put sqlite4.dll in a sqldrivers folder right next to the executable

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcoreapplication.html#libraryPaths

Besides looking at runtime debug info that should popup in a console, you can also add in a call like this to your code:

`bool QSqlDatabase::isValid ()`

Also checking in the docs about `db.open()`, you can call `QSqlError QSqlDatabase::lastError ()` to see what is going on, too.

Hope that helps.